# How can I set up a bunch of attribute builders in a Moose object?

Tags: perl, moose

I have the following five Moose attributes:

```
has ['summary_file', 'html_file', 'url1', 'url2', 'txt_file'] => (
    is       => 'rw',
    isa      => 'Str',
    required => 0,
    lazy     => 1,
    default  => sub { confess "Attribute not set"; },
    );
```

I would like to:

1. Make each of them use its own builder (e.g. set `'summary_file'` use `_build_summary_file`, etc.)
2. Make the default `confess` sub state which (uninitialized) attribute was called (e.g. `"Attribute 'summary_file' not set"`).

I can accomplish the above by writing five separate `has`'s, but perhaps there's a more compact way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something the like following (new working example after your "does not work" comment below):

```
package My::Class;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

for my $attr (qw(x y)) {
    has $attr => (
        is       => 'rw',
        isa      => 'Str',
        required => 0,
        lazy     => 1,
        builder  => "_build_$attr",
    );
}

sub _build_x { rand }
sub _build_y { rand }

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;

use strict; use warnings;

my $o = My::Class->new;

print $o->$_, "\n" for qw(x y);
```

*Note that you cannot specify both a `default` and a `builder`.*

@Oesor points out in a comment something I forgot:

```
has ['summary_file', 'html_file', 'url1', 'url2', 'txt_file'] => (
    is         => 'rw',
    isa        => 'Str',
    required   => 0,
    lazy_build => 1,
);
```

Comment: Or just declare them lazy_build, which defaults to _build_$accessor.

Comment: @Oesor: in that case you will also get a public predicate and clearer, which is often not desirable.

Comment: according to the doc `lazy_build` also sets `required` to true. what does this mean?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-1.19/lib/Moose.pm: "This marks the attribute as being required. This means a value must be supplied during class construction, or the attribute must be lazy and have either a default or a builder. Note that c<required> does not say anything about the attribute's value, which can be undef."

Comment: @Ether: I figure if I don't document those and someone abuses my modules to the point where they start looking for undocumented methods, calling them and things break, they deserve it. Fair point though -- I'd forgotten lazy_build did that.

Comment: I;'m happy with `lazy_build` but btw, `_build_$attr` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @David Thanks for accepting my answer but what does "doesn't seem to work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an attribute to throw an exception on access when it does not have a value set, look at [MooseX::LazyRequire](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aLazyRequire).

If you're looking for a builder to throw an warning if it's called, include that statement in the builder method... OR wrap the accessor/reader method to do that.  (e.g. "`before 'attribute_name' => sub { ...complain... };`")

If you're looking for an way to specify builder methods to an attribute using the same naming convention lazy_build does, see [MooseX::AttributeShortcuts](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aAttributeShortcuts) (supporting '`builder => 1`' as '`builder => "_build_${attribute_name}"`').